# Differential Equation $y'=\sqrt[3]{(4x-y+1)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having problem with sovling this equation.
$$y'=\sqrt[3]{(4x-y+1)^2}$$

I know I have to use change of variables e.g. $z=4x-y+1$ and $z′=4-y'$ but then I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: What kind of differential equation do you get, after changing variables?

Comment: I think it is separable but I can't simplify the integral

Comment: Not every equation is integrable with elementary functions... Solutions may also be defined implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to prove that
$$
\int \frac{dz}{4-z^{2/3}} = -3 z^{1/3} - 3 \log | 2 -z^{1/3}| + 3 \log |2+z^{1/3}| +C.
$$

Comment: I actually having a problem with proving this :)

Comment: http://planetmath.org/integrationoffractionpowerexpressions

Answer (score 0):

with your ansatz $$z=4x-y+1$$ we get $$z'=4-y'$$ and our equation is $$4-z^{2/3}=z'$$ this equation is solvable.